# tree to depthTree conversion

Tags: javascript, object, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

Examples of what I am trying to achieve:
Example 1

```
var input = { // depth of tree is 1
  a: 'a'
}

expect(toDepthTree(input)).to.deep.equal(output)

var output = {
  1: { // 1 equals to depth of input
    a: 'a'
  }
}
```

Example 2:

```
var input = { // depth of tree is 2
  a: {
    b: 'b'
  }
}

expect(toDepthTree(input)).to.equal(output)

var output = {
  2: { // 2 equals to depth of input
    a: {
      b: 'b'
    }    
  }
}
```

These are intro examples to more easily understand the problem. This is the actual test that fails:

```
it('should return depth tree if normal tree is provided', () => {
  const input = {
    a1: {
      b1: {
        c1: {
          d1: 'd1',
          d2: 'd2'
        },
        c2: {
          d3: 'd3'
        }
      },
      b2: {
        c3: 'c3'
      }
    },
    a2: {
      b3: 'b3'
    },
    a3: 'a3'
  }
  const output = {
    1: {
      a3: 'a3'
    },
    2: {
      a2: {
        b3: 'b3'
      }
    },
    3: {
      a1: {
        b1: {
          c2: {
            d3: 'd3'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    4: {
      a1: {
        b1: {
          c1: {
            d1: 'd1',
            d2: 'd2'
          }
        },
        b2: {
          c3: 'c3'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  expect(toLengthTree(input)).to.deep.equal(output)
})
```

I have the following code to perform tree traversal and returning value:

```
function depthOf(tree) {
  let level = 1
  for (const key in tree) {
    if (!tree.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue
    if (tree[key] && tree[key].constructor === Object) {
      const depth = depthOf(tree[key]) + 1
      level = Math.max(depth, level) // this is a problem
    }
  }
  return level
}

function* iterateTree(tree) {
  for (const key in tree) {
    if (tree.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = { [key]: tree[key] }
      yield { value, depth: depthOf(value) }
    }
  }
}

export function toDepthTree(tree) {
  const result = {}
  for (const { value, depth } of iterateTree(tree)) {
    if (!result[depth]) {
      result[depth] = {}
    }
    result[depth] = {
      ...result[depth],
      ...value
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

However the last test fails due to the fact that I get max Depth of a key and therefore the result that I get is:

```
  const output = {
    1: {
      a3: 'a3'
    },
    2: {
      a2: {
        b3: 'b3'
      }
    },
    4: { // notice no 3: { ... } here, but it should be
      a1: {
        b1: {
          c1: {
            d1: 'd1',
            d2: 'd2'
          },
          c2: {
            d3: 'd3'
          }
        },
        b2: {
          c3: 'c3'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am struggling to find a performant approach to do that without creating new Objects or Arrays and just use iterations and recursions.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have, is a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and then stop the iteration. In this case you get only the depth for 4 and not the depth for 3.

Maybe this helps, it overwrites the result set as often as it gets the end of the tree.

```js
function go(o, base, l) {
    if (typeof o === 'object') {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            return go(o[k], base, l + 1);
        });
    } else {
        result[l] = base;
    }
}

var input = { a1: { b1: { c1: { d1: 'd1', d2: 'd2' }, c2: { d3: 'd3' } }, b2: { c3: 'c3' } }, a2: { b3: 'b3' }, a3: 'a3' },
    result = {};

Object.keys(input).forEach(function (k) {
    return go(input[k], input[k], 1);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```